# Datatables not loading for the table containing child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatable

I am trying to apply the jQuery Datatable function in my html table, which contains an another child table in 2nd row of my table.

I am getting the following error in my browser's console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

When I had empty with no data filled, the datatable was working perfectly, while the datatable didn't work properly when I uploaded the data in it.

I am confused what the matter is?

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load tz humanize %}
{% timezone "Asia/Kolkata" %}
    {% block content %}

        <h2 class="align-left">Previous Dispatches</h2>
        {% include 'classroom/teachers/dispatcher_header.html' with active='dispatches' %}


        <div class="card">
            <table class="table table-striped mb-0 dispatches" id="dispatcherhistory">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Vehicles</th>
                    <th>Gross Weight</th>
                    <th>Route</th>
                    <th>Route Distance</th>
                    <th>Route TAT</th>
                    <th>ETD</th>
{#                    <th></th>#}
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <form method="post" novalidate>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for plan in plan %}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.comments }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.pk }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.truck_type }} {{ plan.truck_name }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.weight }}.00 KG</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.origin }}-{{ plan.destination }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.route_distance }} KM</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.route_tat }}</td>
                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.etd }}</td>
                            {#                            <td class="align-middle">{{ plan.eta }}</td>#}
                            <td class="align-middle">
                                <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                        data-target="#multiCollapse{{ plan.pk }}" aria-expanded="false"
                                        aria-controls="multiCollapse{{ plan.pk }}"><img
                                        src="{% static 'img/cardopen.svg' %}" alt="card open"></button>
                            </td>
                            <td class="align-middle"><a href=" {% url 'teachers:quiz_change' plan.pk %}"
                                                        class="btn btn-primary">Raise RFQ</a>
                            </td>
                        <tr class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapse{{ plan.pk }}">
                            <td colspan="5">


                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="rubin{{ plan.pk }}">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3">{{ plan.truck_name }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SKU ID</th>
                                        <th>SKU Name</th>
                                        <th>Quantity</th>
                                    </tr>


                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    {% for x in t_items %}
                                        {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                                            {% for j in ttt %}
                                                {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                                                    {% for k in j %}

                                                        <button onclick="exportTableToCSV()">Download
                                                            Loading Plan
                                                        </button>

                                                        <tr>

                                                            <td>{{ k.pid }}</td>
                                                            <td>{{ k.name }}</td>
                                                            <td>{{ k.weight }}</td>

                                                        </tr>

                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}

                                    {% endfor %}

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>


                            </td>
                            <td colspan="5" class="align-middle">
                                <div class="card card-body iframecard">

                                    <iframe src="{{ plan.route_link }}"></iframe>


                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                    {% empty %}
                        {#                            <td class="bg-light text-center font-italic" colspan="7">You have no dispatch plans yet#}
                        {#                            </td>#}
                        {#                        </tr>#}
                    {% endfor %}
                </form>


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#dispatcherhistory').DataTable({
                    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                    "bDestroy": true
                });
            });


            $('#dispatcherhistory tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                } else {
                    // Open this row
                    row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');
                }
            });

        </script>


    {% endblock %}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Output when no data filled in the table : Datatable is being applied.
Output when I filled the data in the table : Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

This a shot in the dark, but I assume it's is because of missing table header names Or a mismatch between the headers and the number of actual columns.

1. Would you try removing the unwanted columns from both the header and body?
2. In the table body (form), try keeping just the first row there, without the child rows and check if the error still persists.

Comment: As you can see in the code, I have the same number of th and tds. I checked that multiple times now.

Comment: @RubinShah no you are not having neither a valid html tags format, neither the same number of cells & rows respectivelly with the table's header.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have nested row tags ( inside ) on your HTML. there's why you're getting an unexpected error related number of cells and rows